# Scheme - Simple list with three random elements

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I haven't even seen Scheme before today, but need it to write a simple script for GIMP. Basically I'm in need of a list with three random elements from 0 to 255. I then give this list to a function that sets the foreground colour in gimp. I've tried:

```
 (let* ( (x '(( random 255 ) 255 255))) x)
```

And all the variations thereof, but it will instead set the first value of x to a string of (random 255), resulting in an output of:

```
 ((random 255) 255 255)
```

Which naturally the GIMP function will not accept as it expects three numbers.

I tried looking up this problem but only found solutions that are really complex and that I, if I am honest, do not understand at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(random n)` will generate a random number in the interval `[0,n-1]`. So, you can create a random number between 0 and 255 inclusive using `(random 256)`.

To create the list of three values within the mentioned interval, you can define a function as follows:

```
(define (rgb)
  (list (random 256)
        (random 256)
        (random 256)))
```

For example,

```
(rgb)
=> '(55 114 248)
(rgb)
=> '(206 195 169)
(rgb)
=> '(5 157 209)
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this, can't believe I didn't think to try it.